# Initial text and paperclipped-URL for action in UIActivityViewController & UIActivityItemSource?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, ios6

Finally been making it through Apple's (rather dismal) documentation on the new `UIActivityViewController` class and the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol, and I'm trying to send different data sets to different actions called from the activity view. To simplify things, I'm looking at two things.

1. A Facebook posting action, which should say "Check this out!" and also attach a URL to the post (with that cute little paperclip).
2. A Twitter posting action, which should say "Check this out, with #hashtag!" and also attach that same URL (with the same paperclip).

Here's the code I've got implemented right now.

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        return @"Check this out!";
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        return @"Check this out, with #hashtag!";
    }

    return @"";
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"";
}
```

And then when I set up this activity view controller (it's in the same class), this is what I do.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My dilemma is **how to attach that `NSURL` object.** It's relatively easy when calling the iOS 6 SL-class posting modals; you just call the individual methods to attach a URL or an image. How would I go about doing this here?

I'll note that instead of returning `NSString` objects from `-activityViewController:itemForActivityType`, if I return just `NSURL` objects, they show up with that paperclip, with no body text in the post. If I return an array of those two items, nothing shows up at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Evidently it was as simple as this: passing in an array to the first argument of `UIActivityViewController`'s init call, with each item in the array handling a different data type that will end up in the compose screen. `self` handles the text, and the second object (the `NSURL`) attaches the URL.

```
NSArray *items = @[self, [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://this-is-a-url.com"]];
UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]  initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Really wish there was more on this, but here it is.

Comment: Note that a single UIActivityItemSource can only return a placeholder for a single piece of data (no returning NSArrays for `activityViewControllerPlaceHolderItem:`. For more info see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029340/uiactivityitemsource-protocole-set-complex-object

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that other question. I've more-or-less forsaken `UIActivityViewController` for now (I've wasted too many hours getting it to do what I want), since it's so inflexible, but that subclass mentioned in your link seems like a definite step in the right direction.

Comment: I've been struggling with this same problem. It seems odd that they didn't define constants for possible data types so we could key against those. UIActivityViewController is a great idea, but the implementation is a bit wack right now.

Comment: @BenKreeger, I really wish it didn't work this way because I cannot comprehend how Apple thinks this makes any sense. Thanks for your answer because under no circumstances would I have thought of doing it this way.

Comment: @rob5408 Haha don't mention it. I think things have improved for the better in the latest handful of releases, especially iOS 8, but originally the docs were sparse and the API was confusing.

Comment: I ended up with a similar technique to support printing and email.  Self handles the email, implementing the UIActivityItemSource as you did.  The printing is handled with a UIActivityItemProvider subclass, whose item property is a UIWebView's viewPrintFormatter.  The final object in the array is a UIPrintInfo object, providing the jobName and orientation (UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape).  We all deserve a pat on the back for the various aspects of this that we deduced!