# UIActivityItemSource Protocole set complex object

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using iOS 6 new way to share information : `UIActivityViewController`. To select the shared data depending on the media (facebook, twitter or mail) my view controller implement the `UIActivityItemSource` Protocol as follow :

```
- (IBAction)onShareButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:nil];

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}

#pragma mark - UIActivityItemSource Protocol

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        NSArray *items = @[@"message facebook", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myUrlFacebook.com"]];
        return items;
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        NSArray *items = @[@"message twitter", [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.myUrlTwitter.com"]];
        return items;
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
        NSArray *items = @[@"message mail", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myUrlMail.com"]];
        return items;
    }

        NSArray *items = @[@"Not a proper Activity", [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myUrlMail.com"]];
    return items;
}

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"PlaceHolder";
}
```

When I'm returning a simple NSString for `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` the string is well used by my `UIActivityViewController`, but I can't find a way to use an `Array` !

According to Apple Documentation it should be possible :

> This method returns the actual data object to be acted on by an activity object
>   [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Does anyone ever use this `UIActivityItemSource` Protocol with Arrays, or is there a use full tutorial to do that ?

Note : I also got this error on the console, it may help ...

> Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.mobilemail failed
>
> Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.apple.mobilemail

Comment: Have you found out what that message about com.apple.mobilemail is in the console?

Comment: The console error only occurs in the simulator, where the mail-app simply doesn't exist. It can be ignored.

Comment: @Tommecpe: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After spending a significant amount of time trying to figure this one out, it seems it isn't possible to pass it an `NSArray` of items. So I extended `UIActivityViewController` to make it possible.

[RDActivityViewController](https://github.com/rdougan/RDActivityViewController)

Comment: Thank you very very much. I will test it as soon has I can.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the above?  What method doesn't allow an NSArray?  I'm having the same issue and can't understand the answer.  Tnx.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I'd been banging my head against a wall for a few hours over this issue. RDActivityViewController works great.

Comment: @rdougan  I am facing issue with integration in my swift project : '-[RDActivityViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x133220d60'

Answer (score 23):

A single object conforming to `UIactivityItemSource` can only return a single piece of data for `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:`, no `NSArray`s.

You could overcome this by creating and passing two `UIActivityItemSource`s in the `activityItems` part of the initial `initWithActivityItems:`. Each source can pass a placeholder value, but can return something blank on `itemForActivityType` so you don't actually have to use that particular type of data depending on the activity.

Or just use that cool extension mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I had to do that exactly and posted my solution here... maybe it helps someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70866445/611879

Answer (score 0):

`- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType` function only return one result.it can't return NSArray. if you wangt return multiple type of item. You need creat multipe class which conform UIActivityItemSource protol. Like the first answer.In addition, after debugging, I found that RDActivityViewController in the second answer has a memory leak problem